# I want to tag the location on the map when user clicks on the specific location

Tags: android, location

I am creating an app that tracks nearby schools,hospitals etc in android. The problem I am facing is that I want to store some locations that would be tagged by the user and display them to other users on map. I am using google map api for the nearby schools and  hospitals but I can't tag the location. If anyone can solve my problem?

Comment: Question - can the user pick any place on the map? or just from the markers

Comment: Any Location....

Comment: I really don't think that this is practical, how will you implement this if the map  is really zoomed out and every click will click entire city

Comment: I think I couldn't explain my problem. At some part or some place there is a school, hospital or resturant which is not tagged... So can you please tell that how tagging will work (in code only) like if I want to tag in a location using my app and saving its attributes (i.e. Latitude and Longitude and name) in my db

Comment: Have a look at my answer - hope this will be helpful

Answer (score 0):

You can try to set click listener when your map is ready and add a marker for every click like this :

```
    mGoogleMAp.setOnMapClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMapClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onMapClick(LatLng latLng) {
            mGoogleMAp.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(latLng));
        }
    });
```

Comment: I think let me try... Thanks bro I can even understand it clearly :)